# What is the equivalent to EF 5's Update/Create Code First model creation in EF 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, asp.net-4.5, entity-framework-6

For Example:

I have a MVC 5 Web application project.

I already have an existing database.

I'm doing the Code First route.

In previous versions of Entity Framework, you would right-click on your project and have access to Entity Framework in that context menu, and you could generate all of your Model files there.

Now, Entity Framework v6 doesn't seem to have the same functionality, or maybe it's moved.

How would I update my models in Entity Framework 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably had [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) installed. When right-clicking on your project it gives you EF context menu.